# Unable to enter data into SQL DB

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert values to a SQL DB where I pull data from a dictionary. I ran into a problem when my program tries to enter `0xqb_QWQDrabGr7FTBREfhCLMZLw4ztx` into a column named VersionId. The following is my sample code and error.

```
cursor.execute("""insert into [TestDB].[dbo].[S3_Files] ([Key],[IsLatest],[LastModified],[Size(Bytes)],[VersionID]) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""",(item['Key'],item['IsLatest'],item['LastModified'],item['Size'],item['VersionId']))
conn_db.commit() 

pymssql.ProgrammingError: (102, "Incorrect syntax near 'qb_QWQDrabGr7FTBREfhCLMZLw4ztx'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")
```

Based on the error I assume SQL does not like the `0x` in the beginning of the VersionId string because of security issues. If my assumption is correct, what are my options? I also cannot change the value of the VersionId.

Edit: This what I get when I print that cursor command
`insert into [TestDB].[dbo].[S3_Files] ([Key],[IsLatest],[LastModified],[Size(Bytes)],[VersionID]) values (Docs/F1/Trades/Buy/Person1/Seller_Provided_-_Raw_Data/GTF/PDF/GTF's_v2/NID3154229_23351201.pdf,True,2015-07-22 22:05:38+00:00,753854,0xqb_QWQDrabGr7FTBREfhCLMZLw4ztx)`

Edit 2: The odd thing is that when I try to enter the insert command manually on SQL management studio, it doesn't like the (') in the path name in the first parameter, so I escaped the character, added (') to each values except the number and the command worked. At this point I am pretty stumped on why the insert is not working.

Edit 3: I decided to do a try except on every insert and I see that the ones that VersionIds that get caught have the pattern `0x....`. Again, does anyone know if my assumption of security correct?

Comment: you should try create a string variable strSQL first and then `cursor.execute(strSQL)` so you can debug what is inside strSQL

Comment: Can you use the SQL statement and run it in phpAdmin or something similar to see if it works?

Comment: @Drewdin I had to change the command accordingly to work on PHP, I used site demo.phpmyadmin.net to try it out `insert into temp (KeyHolder,IsLatest,LastModified,Size,VersionID) values ('pmtg-dox/CCM/Trades/Buy/BLT_1507_01/Seller_Provided_-_Raw_Data/BPO/PDF/BLT_BPO''s_v2/NID3154229_23351201_BPO.pdf',True,'2015-07-22 22:05:38+00:00',753854,'0xqb_QWQDrabGr7FTBREfhCLMZLw4ztx')` and this command worked. What I had to fix the the bracket and add in ' to the first value and the last value.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's what happens when our libraries try to be smarter than us...

No SQL server around to test, but I assume the reason the 0x values are failing is because the way pymssql passes the parameter causes the server to interprete this as a hexadecimal string and the 'q' following the '0x' does not fit its expectations of 0-9 and A-F chars.

I don't have enough information to know if this is a library bug and/or if it can be worked around; the pymssql documentation is not very extensive, but I would try the following:

- if you can, check in MSSQL Profiler what command is actually coming in
- build your own command as a string and see if the error persists (remember Bobby Tables before putting that in production, though: https://xkcd.com/327/)
- try to work around it by adding quotes etc
- swith to another library / use SQLAlchemy